# Django CheckConstraint With IntegrityError

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a constraint that I'd like to add in my Django Model. I thought the `CheckConstraint` method would help to catch the error when the input does not meet the constraint. However, when I saved the model with an invalid input, e.g. percentage = 101, an error page was shown with IntegrityError. Does anyone here know how to properly use this method to validate the input?

```
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(percentage__gte=1)
                & Q(percentage__lte=100),
                name="Please enter a valid percentage",
            )
        ]
```

**Solution**:
I ended up using this to solve my problem

```
    def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        super().clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
        if self.percentage and (
            self.percentage < 0 or self.percentage > 100
        ):
```

Answer (score 1):

The `constraints` are (only) enforced at the database side, and thus result in `IntegrityError`s when the given condition is not met.

In order to raise the correct validation error, you add validators to the model fields, for example:

```
from django.core import validators

class MyModel(models.Model):
    percentage = models.IntegerField(validators=[
        validators.MinValueValidator(1),
        validators.MaxValueValidator(100)
    )]

    # …
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it seems like `min_value` and `max_value` are not valid parameters.

Comment: @PotatoProgrammer: indeed, one should sue the `MinValueValidator` and `MaxValueValidator`, see edit.